# Node templating engine for colored output to console

Tags: node.js, colors, console, template-engine

How to render **colored** text to the console produced by a templating engine which supports looping and variable substitution.

I've done some tests with [swig](https://github.com/paularmstrong/swig), but it simply escapes the `\u001b[32m` stuff.

Is there something in between `sprintf` and a real HTML templating engine?

**Update:**
I've tried `swig` for a while now and just using `console.log` would've actually been more maintainable/readable :)

Am I the only one that would find something for outputting text to the console based on a model useful? Or am I approaching this from the wrong angle?

Comment: Can you share the code of what you've attempted so far?

Comment: I tried using swig but the result was a total mess: newlines and whitespace don't matter in HTML but when output to the console excess whitespace is visible to the user.

Answer (score 1):

Although this doesn't solve the problem of a templating system, it might help you towards what it is you are trying to achieve. There are two different modules that I would suggest you have a look at:

### [chalk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chalk) - *"Terminal string styling done right. Much color."*

There is a node module called *chalk* that allows you to define colors/styles though a very simple api.

It is compatible with `sprintf` substitution and can be combined with `console.log` to log pretty colored formatted output.

### [bunyan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bunyan) - *"a JSON logging library for node.js services"*

If however you are wanting to use it for **logs**, I'd suggest having a look at *bunyan*. It allows you to basically send anything to your logs formatted as JSON. It adds extra data like timestamps and error levels, so you don't have to. The output is just JSON, so it can easily be consumed programatically.

By piping the `std.out` into `bunyan`, it will colorise and format the output, making it easier to inspect.

Comment: bunyan: Imagine I execute the following: `myGlobalPackage print status` which does some stuff and then prints a report to the console. It's really output for the user not just logging.

Comment: chalk: I know about chalk and colors, the idea is to separate my processing from the `console.logs`. These packages can print colored text but they do not decouple presentation from logic (which is what I want to achieve here)